# Clockify Saved Reports for Half Month

Tags: clockify

Is there anyway to save reports in Clockify for a half-month period (i.e. 1-15th of the month and 16th-end)? We pay twice monthly and ideally can save off a report that can be used for a half month period.

UPDATE

Choosing a 15 day range 1st-15th and then scrolling does not work as Clockfy maintains the range size (15 days) rather than the concept of half month.

UPDATE2

Perhaps the question can better be phrased as: "does Clockify have any sort of semantic period of time for 'half-month' (aka semimonthly) that will be maintained when advancing time periods?"

Comment: It's possible this might belong in some other SE site? Or do mean some JS API?

Comment: There is a specific `clockify` tag and their support told me to post the question here.

Comment: Are you asking about some web interface of the Clockify web service, or are you asking about some Java Script Application Programming Interface Clockify provided your company with?

Comment: Updated again with further clarification.